# Using tags prefixed with aws: in IAM policies

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I have a use case where I'm creating a set of resources such as EC2 instances and S3 buckets using CloudFormation. I see that Cloudformation adds tags to both EC2 instances and S3 buckets with the tag being of the format

`aws:cloudformation:stack-name: <stack-name>`

I'm trying to write an IAM policy which has tag based permissions. The policy looks as follows:

`{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowToDescribeAll",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:*",
                "s3:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "aws:ResourceTag/aws:cloudformation:stack-name": "mystackname"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllPermissions",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:Describe*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}`

Now when I attempt to perform a S3 put object API call using the CLI, I see AccessDenied permissions. Same goes when I attempt to terminate the instance which has that specific tag. I couldn't find any specific IAM documentation which mentions that we cannot use tags prefixed with `aws:` in IAM policies. Does anybody know what the issue might possibly be? Or is it the case that the context key `aws:ResourceTag` is invalid?

Comment: You need to use intrinsic functions within cloud formation : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference.html

Comment: @Rajesh: I'm sorry, but I didn't understand your comment. How does using intrinsic functions help me overcome this problem?

Answer (score 2):

TLDR; I hunted for more docs and I figured that the context key `aws:ResourceTag` isn't something valid/supported right now. Found the documentation here - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_condition-keys.html, that documentation only provides aws:RequestTag as a valid context key.

To add context keys specific to a service, I had to dig deeper and find this document - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/list_amazonec2.html, which has the ec2:ResourceTag/tagKey context key. So, once I changed my IAM policy to have `"ec2:ResourceTag/aws:cloudformation:stack-name": "mystackname"`, I started to see successes.

Answer (score 0):

I think that not all of the "Action"s supporting resource-level permissions.
To eliminate the issue, for testing, please try to use the minimum of the permissions instead of "*", for example:

```
"Action": ["ec2:StartInstances","ec2:StopInstances"]
```

If that works, separate the policy into two sections.

I hope it helps.
Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I do know that not all actions support resource level permissions. I was using the TerminateInstances API which does support resource level permissions.